# How to create a loop that updates on message? (paho-mqtt)

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm trying to create a typical sensor activated light for my driveway. The unit will be an Arduino(Wemos) connected to a PIR-sensor, which will communicate with a raspberry pi working as a central 'control point'. It is working well, however I can't find a way to control the delay on the light. I want to be able to do it from the rPi.

The Arduino sends a message if movement is detected, if it's dark outside, the rPi tells the Arduino to turn on the light.

Now I also want the rPi to decide the 'delay' based on the last movement, e.g. turn the lights on for 30 seconds, if further movement is detected zero the timer.

My current code(only the rPi side):

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import arrow
from astral import Astral

inTopic = "wemos/status"
outTopic = "wemos/cmds"

Astral().solar_depression = 'civil'
city_name = 'Copenhagen'
city = Astral()[city_name]


def day() -> bool:
    now = arrow.now('Europe/Copenhagen')
    sun = city.sun(date=now, local=True)
    return (now > sun['dawn'] and now < sun['dusk'])


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print(f"Connected with result code {str(rc)}")
    client.subscribe(inTopic)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(f'{msg.topic}: {str(msg.payload)}')
    if msg.topic == inTopic and msg.payload == b'Motion detected':
        if not day():
            client.publish(outTopic, payload="lightOn")
    elif msg.topic == inTopic and msg.payload == b'No motion detected':
        client.publish(outTopic, payload="lightOff")


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("192.168.0.14", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

This will turn on the lights if it's dark outside, but when the Arduino returns 'No motion detected' it will turn off the light.

I want to register the message while in a loop e.g(very pseudo cody):

```
on_message:

if message == 'Motion detected':
    client.publish(outTopic, payload="lightOn")
    counter = 30

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        counter -= 1
        if counter == 0:
            client.publish(outTopic, payload="lightOff")
            break
        if new_message = 'Motion detected':
            counter = 30
```

However I don't know how to handle new messages while handling the first one in my `on_message` function. I'm looking into the `loop()`, `loop_start()` and `loop_stop()` methods of the paho library, but I can't quite seem to grok it...

Thank you sincerely!

Comment: I've stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756975/processing-a-received-message-using-paho-mqtt-in-python?rq=1) question. Here it is done with global variables. I'll try this and maybe update.

Comment: You should probably implement a proper state machine triggered by messages from subscription to the light and movement sensor and using timers to determine e.g. 30s. Then you’ll have a more generic and flexible solution.

Comment: Hi Barny, thank you for your time. I'm sorry, but I'm not very experienced, and don't fully understand, can you elaborate?
Main thing 'proper state machine'? If by 'timer' you mean the electrical components on the PIR, I could. However the sensor/Arduino is going to be in an inaccessible place, so I'd like to be able to adjust the time centrally, i.e. the rPi.